# Is there any way can help code return value is const reference?

Tags: c++, reference

Suppose I have a class `A`, the class is copyable, but it will take a lot to copy it.

Suppose I have a class `B`, it can return a const reference of `A`.

```
class B
{
public:
...
    const A& obtainA() const
    {
       return a;
    }

private:
    A a;
};
```

When I want to use A from B, I think the best practice is accessed A in B by const reference

```
B b;
const A& a = b.obtainA(); // do not needs to the heavy copy operation of A, good.
```

However, I always forget the const reference, my code looks like follow.

```
B b;
A a = b.obtainA(); // leads to the heavy copy operation of A, not good
```

It not only leads to the heavy copy operation but also the unsafety.
If the `a` call the non-const member function by mistake, it will leads to the member `a` in b be changed out of class.

Is there exists any way can help me to return const reference?
I want something like, if not returned by reference, the code can not be compiled.
Or any other advice is OK.

Thanks for your time.

### Concrete applications

`A` in my application is the `shared array`. The data stored in the array is shared, it just something like the `std::shared_ptr`, but manage array of object but not single object.

The array is designed can be shared to reduce the copy overhead. The `A` is copyable because the array should be copyable.

The array is a widely used class, thus it is often a member of Array's user, that is the `B` in this question.

Comment: The only compiler-enforced way to prevent that is for `A` to be non-copyable. But since you noted that `A` is indeed copyable, then the compiler cannot enforce only assigning to references, as it cannot guess your intentions.

Comment: what you describe seems like a bad design on `A`, not `B` (e.g. a copy can modify origin instance / do not prevent copy when it should)

Comment: return a [`std::reference wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)?

Comment: consider using pointer

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I've add some explanation, I more aim at OP's *unsafety*, But if possible, OP can also make A non-copy-able.

Comment: @ OP re:your edit.   `shared_ptr` is not expensive to copy, can you also share the real code that make `A` expensive to copy?

Comment: @appleapple, even if the copy is not expensive, the unsafety leads to the uncomfortable.

Comment: @XuHui you wouldn't feel unsafe with `shared_ptr`, because it's *meant to be shared*.

Comment: If you fell *unsafe* to copy an object but still allow it, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `A` non-copyable, and provide a method to do the copy explicitly.

```
class A {
  private:
    A(A const &);  // expensive copy
  public:
    A make_copy() { return *this; }
};
```

The `make_copy` method will create the expensive copy, but other code will no be able to make copies implicitly, since the copy-constructor is private.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want an object to be modified, make the object itself constant:

```cpp
B const b;
A a = b.obtainA(); // nope, not allowed
```

I personally believe that everything should be constant unless there is a good reason for it not to be.

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake to forget to add the `obtainA()` should be const.